# Timeit module -passing arguments to python timeit module

Tags: python, timeit

from python timeit module i want to check how much time does it take to print the following , how to do so,

```
import timeit
x = [x for x in range(10000)]
timeit.timeit("print x[9999]")
d=[{i:i} for i in x]
timeit.timeit("print d[9999]")

NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
NameError: global name 'd' is not defined
```

Comment: unrelated: you could also use the command-line interface: `python -mtimeit -s'x = list(range(10000)); d = [{i:i} for i in x]' 'd[9999]'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#examples):

> To give the `timeit` module access to functions you define, you can pass a *setup* parameter which contains an import statement

In your case, that would be e.g.:

```
timeit.timeit('print d[9999]', 
              setup='from __main__ import d')
```

Comment: Not infinite, but `timeit` runs 1,000,000 times by default. Did you read the documentation at all?!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
import timeit

x = [x for x in range(10000)]
d = [{i: i} for i in x]

for i in [x, d]:
    t = timeit.timeit(stmt="print(i[9999])", number=100, globals=globals())
    print(f"took: {t:.4f}")
```

Output:

```
took: 0.0776
took: 0.0788
```

Please notice I added number=100, so it runs 100 times each test. By default it 1,000,000 times.